# What statistical test to use?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, continuous-data

I would like to test the impact of education on risky sex, controlling for several demographic factors.

I have one categorical, ordinal independent variable and more than three dependent variables. The dependent variables are both categorical and continuous. It is likely that some dependent variables are related to each other. In addition, I would like to control for demographic variables such as gender and age.

I am seeking help to find the appropriate test for these variables. Thank you.

Comment: General/Generalized structural equation modeling might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is really rare that you have one Independent variable and three dependent- often is the other way round and you have more independent variables... but path analysis or SEM (structural equation modelling) allows you to have multiple dependent variables.